# on click button works only after refresh my page

Tags: javascript

In my website (net core 2. 2) I have this code so to assign tasks to clerks

```
<script>
  
 $(document).on("click", ".assignToClerk", function () {
    var Assignment =
    {
        ID: $('#UserID').val(),
        TaskID: @Model.RequestID,

    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Request/NewTask/",
        dataType: "json",

        data: Assignment,
        processData: true,
        success: $.notify("success assign")

           });

        });

</script>
```

The problem is that my button works only if I refresh the  page.

Any idea? thank you

Comment: please open your console and tell us if soe error appear

Comment: yes you are right I see `Uncaught TypeError: $.notify is not a function` but I call notify.js in my page

Answer (score 0):

Put the code inside

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //your code
});
```

Add the scripts in the body of the page instead of the head of the page.

Comment: thank you for your reply....I have already try this but no luck!

Comment: did you place the script at the end of your body tag?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
 <button class="assignToClerk">
    Click
    </button>
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.assignToClerk').on("click", function () {
      alert("Testing")
     //code
    
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try after code.

```js
function test(){
   alert("Hi");
}

window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('btn').click();
  
var scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
scriptTag.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(scriptTag);
}
```

```html
<button id="btn" onclick="test()">Click me</button>
```